# ¿Como pasar valores numericos por argumentos de linea de comandos a una JComboBox?

Tags: java

Que tal, primer post aquí y me gustaria saber si me pudieran ayudar con esta duda. Tengo que realizar una calculadora por medio de JComboBoxes en Java y lo que necesito hacer es pasar números para realizar las operaciones, por medio de argumentos en la linea de comandos y que estos aparezcan en la JComboBox. He tratado de hacer de diferentes formas pero me marca errores en los tipos de datos o que no puede pasarse el contenido. Quise poner los números de forma estática y probar la operación suma pero tengo un error de nueva cuenta con los tipos de datos.

Este es el codigo que llevo con los numeros de forma estatica:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculadora implements ActionListener{
JFrame marco;
JPanel ventana;
JLabel lbl1;
JButton boton;
JComboBox<String> cb2;
JComboBox<Integer> cb1;
JComboBox<Integer> cb3;
String input;
String[] operadores = {"+","-","*","/"};
Integer[] numerosOperaciones = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int resultado;

public static void main(String args[]){
    /*
        Parte la entrada utilizando el método split(String delim) de la clase String
        con este método puedes partir una cadena en 2 cadenas nuevas a partir del
        delimitador que tú le mandes. Por ejemplo, si tienes la cadena a=3, puedes
        usar el método split en esa cadena con el delimitador "=" y hacer esto te crea
        2 cadenas nuevas, "a" y "3", puedes usar estas cadenas para pasarlas a tu JComboBox.

        Ejemplo de uso para este código:

        Para i = 0 hasta args.length:
            letras[i] = args[i].split("=")[0];
            numeros[i] = args[i].split("=")[1];

        y de esta manera ya partiste tu entrada en 2 cadenas nuevas que puedes usar
        en tus JComboBox
     */
    String input = args[0];
    Calculadora grafico = new Calculadora(input);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(cb2.getSelectedItem()=="+"){
        resultado = (Integer.parseInt(cb1.getSelectedItem()) + Integer.parseInt(cb3.getSelectedItem()));
        lbl1.setText("= " + resultado);
    }
}

public Calculadora(String input){
    this.input = input;

    // No necesitas poner el índice a la fuerza, el JComboBox siempre te selecciona
    // el primer elemento de la lista que tú le mandes

    marco = new JFrame("Calculadora");
    ventana = new JPanel();
    ventana.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
    lbl1 = new JLabel("Resultado");
    boton = new JButton("Respuesta");
    cb1 = new JComboBox<>(numerosOperaciones);
    cb1.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cb1.addActionListener(this);
    cb2 = new JComboBox<>(operadores);
    // Lo mismo que con el cb1, no ocupas ponerle el índice a la fuerza, la clase te lo pone predeterminado
    // en la primera posición de la lista.
    cb2.setSelectedIndex(1);
    cb2.addActionListener(this);
    cb3 = new JComboBox<>(numerosOperaciones);
    cb3.setSelectedIndex(0);
    cb3.addActionListener(this);
    boton.addActionListener(this);

    ventana.add(cb1);
    ventana.add(cb2);
    ventana.add(cb3);
    ventana.add(boton);
    ventana.add(lbl1);
    marco.getContentPane().add(ventana);
    marco.setVisible(true);
    marco.setSize(400,400);
    marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
}
```

¿De que manera puedo pasar los números de la linea de comandos al Jcombobox? ¿Hay algo que no estoy tomando en cuenta?

Gracias.

Comment: Debo de ingresar los numeros de la calculadora por medio de la consola

Comment: Uhm, tu viste que los comentarios en el código ya te dan una explicación como hacerlo? Que parte de esta explicación no entendiste?

Comment: Si, ya lo observe. Entiendo un poco lo que se puede hacer pero me entra en duda en que, una vez que se realiza el split y se tiene el numero como se pasaria la variable numeros al JComboBox. Seria al igual como en el codigo, cb.new JComboBos<>(numeros)?  Tambien en la declaracion principal si trabajo con la variable numeros se dejaria como Integer JComboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imaginemos que arrancas tu app en la siguiente forma:

```
javaw -jar App.jar a=1 b=3 c=5 d=2
```

Entonces puedes extraer tus arreglos en el método main como:

```
public static main(String... args){
    String[] nombres = new String[args.length];
    Integer[] numeros = new Integer[args.length];
    for (int i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
        String[] data = args[i].split("="); // te deja con los componentes separados por "="
        nombres[i] = data[0];
        numeros[i] = Integer.valueOf(data[1]); // quizas quieres chequear el formato aquí
    }
    // mas adelante puedes crear tu combo box como
    JComboBox<String> nombreBox = new JComboBox(nombres);
    JComboBox<Integer> numeroBox = new JComboBox(numeros);
```

Este código te crea combo boxes con:

```
nombres[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
numeros[] = { 1, 3, 5, 2 };
```

Si necesitas saber más, no dudes de comentar.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Pudo resolver mi problema que tenia :D

Comment: De nada, pero comentarios que se tratan exclusivamente a mensajes de agradecimiento tratemos de evitar en stackoverflow. ;) Aceptar una respuesta y/o votar se interpreta en la misma forma. Se siente un poco extraño  para muchos primero, pero el concepto es de concentrar las publicaciones a lo informativo lo más que posible. :) (yo normalmente escondo mis cortesías en comentarios que contienen un poco más información para pasar piola ;) )

Comment: De acuerdo, ya me quedo mas claro. Gracias!